# How to upload a image in mobile using jqurymobile in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

Hi all i have develop a small MVc3 Application in that i have integrating the Jquerymobile app .My qusetion is in my application i have a upload controle it is working in Desctop device for uploading but not working in Mobile device is there any another control to upload a file from Mobile device please help me..

Comment: ok thank you for giving a good suggetion to me.. i will ..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this MSDN example download.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852592.aspx